# Google Chrome cannot open from application using Process.Start()

Tags: c#, google-chrome, process, web

I have written windows application in c# that opens website in default browser on label click event. My default browser is Google Chrome. So when I start my application and click on label, it fails to open website in Chrome. Chrome throws error "Failed to create data directory - Google Chrome cannot read and write to its data directory". I am using "System.Diagnostics.Process.Start" to start process.

One interesting thing is, when I close my application and reopen it. It sucessfully opens website in default Chrome browser. :)

I tried by using various options of Process.StartInfo but never succeed. Below is the method used to run website.

I am using Windows 8-64Bit and .Net Framework 4. Could you please help me on this.

Test1:

```
public static void RunWebClient()
{
    Process proc = new Process();

    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey subKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"http\shell\open\command");
    String DefaultBrowser = subKey.GetValue(null).ToString();

    if (DefaultBrowser != null)
    {
        int startIndex = DefaultBrowser.IndexOf("\"") + 1;
        int endIndex = DefaultBrowser.IndexOf("\"", startIndex);
        string RegDefaultBrowserPath = DefaultBrowser.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);

        proc.StartInfo.FileName = RegDefaultBrowserPath;
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"http://localhost/Test/";
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        proc.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = false;
        proc.Start();
    }
}
```

Test2:

```
public static void RunWebClient()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://localhost/Test/");
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is relevant, but this line `proc.StartInfo.FileName = RegDefaultBrowserPath;` isn't necessary when leveraging `ShellExecute`. Further, setting `LoadUserProfile` to `false` is suspect to me. Just launch the URL with the shell and leave the rest alone.

Comment: Do you have things like UAC turned on?

Comment: For path manipulations, use the `System.IO.Path` class, not simple string functions.

Comment: @neoistheone proc.StartInfo.FileName must be provided, else it throws error "Cannot start process because a file name has not been provided". You right, LoadUserProfile is not required but I thought it could causing chrome data directory issue so I used it.

Comment: @lan My machine's UAC is set to Deafult

Comment: @xxbbcc Thanks for your reply. Yes, I can use System.IO.Path to get file name

Answer (score 0):

I would try to add the WorkingDirectory to your ProcessStartInfo class

```
proc.StartInfo.FileName = Path.GetFileName(RegDefaultBrowserPath);
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(RegDefaultBrowserPath);
```

Passing the full file name into the FileName property is not enough to set the current working directory for the launched file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! I tried it but same error. I am facing this issue on Windows 8 only and not for Windows 7.

Comment: Have you tried to MOVE the Arguments value in the FileName property? I mean, you are just trying to use the default browser (Chrome or else), so let the shell choose it. Moving the Arguments value in the FileName property should launch the current browser.

Comment: Yes, I have tried by moving arguments to FileName property. Also I am facing this issue only with Chrome which is my default browser.

Comment: Another thing, when I run chrome as administrator; it runs successfully. But I can't use it as it asks password for normal user which is not allowed.

if ((System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6) && (DefaultBrowserPath.IndexOf("chrome") != -1))
{
 proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas"; 
}

Comment: After debugging code, I found that application get launched by one service through Win32 API CreateProcessAsUser. So root cause of problem should be permission issue that need to set before launching application. I am trying to set permissions using securityAttributes parameter of CreateProcessAsUser.

Comment: It seems to be a plausible cause. I cannot reproduce your problem here. Hope you have found the right track